# HUD-1 limit on realtor commission rebate?

Tags: united-states, mortgage, real-estate

My wife and I are buying a new house and we are using the builder's mortgage company.

Assume our HUD-1 breaks out like this (numbers manufactured to hide real transaction amount):

```
Line 103 - Settlement charges to borrower: $5000
Line 204 - Settlement charges paid by seller: $4000
Line 205 - Settlement charges paid by Broker: $1000
Line 700 - Total Real Estate Broker Fees: $4000
```

Line 700 is 3% of the total transaction; it is paid by the builder.  Line 700 is the full 3% commission expected by a typical realtor.

In terms of credits / debits towards us (the buyer), this is how the actual HUD-1 breaks out for those lines:

```
Line 103 - Settlement charges to borrower: $5000      [Buyer Debit]
Line 204 - Settlement charges paid by seller: $4000   [Buyer Credit]
Line 205 - Settlement charges paid by Broker: $1000   [Buyer Credit]
Line 700 - Total Real Estate Broker Fees: $4000       [Seller Debit]
```

When we signed the agreement with the realtor, we worked it out so the realtor would take 1.5% as commission and pay 1.5% towards our closing.  We also negotiated the amount in Line 204 with the builder.

Now here we are days before closing, and the builder's lender refuses to allow more than $1000 of the realtor's commission towards our closing costs (reference Line 205).  They claim it is *illegal* for us to receive outside money at closing that exceeds the aggregate in Line 103 of the HUD-1.  Unfortunately, I was depending on the realtor's 1.5% contribution ($2000, in this fake example) to offset the cost of some options we selected for the house.

### Question

In this case, is it illegal for the realtor to contribute the full 1.5% on Line 205 (which means we should be getting $2000, not $1000)?

Comment: Line 103 are your total charges, $5K, which you are getting back on ll 204/205, so net is zero cost, right? Were you expecting to pocket some cash at closing?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer, ha there is no cash to pocket, I'm showing a fraction of the HUD-1 and we're still taking over $10k of personal money to closing even if we managed to convince people to do this... I want to apply the positive credit towards insurance, taxes or principal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing about the HUD-1 nor federal low specifies a minimum or maximum for commissions, rebates, points, or anything like that. The purpose of the document is to show the numbers in a concise and standard way, to avoid shenanigans by any of the parties.

I'm sure you already know that the builder's lender is blowing smoke. I have heard of lenders balking at the borrower walking away from the closing table with money. But I've never heard of a lender capping the amount of agent (or seller) paid closing costs; certainly not as low as a paltry $1000.

Call their bluff. If they won't let the transaction go through, let it fail. They'll either back off, or you can go find a less brain-dead lender.